# React add cart refactoring - unknown added state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add items to a cart without redux. I works but I am dont think I did it properly because I get a weird quantity value.

How it works so far.
You click an item button it passes in props to the handleAddCartItem(). The props are addedItem which is the name of the item and addedItemPrice.

**The default state**

```
  state = {
term: "",
cart: [
  {
    item: "",
    price: 0,
    quantity: 0
  }
]};
```

**how handler works.**

```
  handleAddCartItem = (addedItem, addedItemPrice) => {
// check if already in cart
let index = this.state.cart.findIndex(el => el.item === addedItem);

if (index == -1) {
  console.log("item new to cart");
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    cart: [
      ...prevState.cart,
      {
        item: addedItem,
        price: addedItemPrice,
        quantity: 1
      }
    ]
  }));
} else {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
    quantity: (prevState.cart[index].quantity += 1)
  }));
} };
```

**The weird extra quantity state screenshot.**
[image: screen shot of react dev tools]

I am new to react so the code is probably gross sorry.

My logic in the handler
- checks in item name is already inside the cart array.

-if it newly added item then new object is added to array.

-if item is already in array then I use the index of the item currently inside the array and only update its quantity.

I don't understand why I have an extra quantity state added =/

Any advice appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive code speaks for itself but if you're confused about something, ask me.

```
handleAddCartItem = (addedItem, addedItemPrice) => {
  // check if already in cart
  let index = this.state.cart.findIndex(el => el.item === addedItem);

  if (index == -1) {
    console.log("item new to cart");
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      cart: [
        ...prevState.cart,
        {
          item: addedItem,
          price: addedItemPrice,
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    }));
  } else {
    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      quantity: (prevState.cart[index].quantity += 1)
    }));

    // HOW IT SHOULD BE
    this.setState(prevState => {
      let newCart = [...prevState.cart];
      newCart[index].quantity += 1;
      return {cart: newCart}; 
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOh that makes sense. Thank you I spent so long on this today was soul crushed. Thanks. 

Edit: Not sure how to update as answered. Hopefully mod ticks it. thanks

Comment: Yes, you always have to return "root" item in `setState` if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

quantity in the necessary item object needs to be incremented. But instead another variable `quantity` was created at the root. Try updating the else block to this :

```
else {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    cart: prevState.cart.map((item, itemIndex) => {
      if(itemIndex === index) {
        return {
          ...item,
          quantity: item.quantity + 1
        }
      }
      return item
    })
  }));
}
```